# The existence of an optimal solution in a MILP guarantees existence of the optimal solution in the relaxation problem?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'm following a description of the Branch and Bound Method.

But I don't understand at all, that if you assume a MILP problem has an optimal solution it implies that the relaxation problem has also an optimal solution.

Let
$$\mbox{MILP}:\hspace{0,2cm} \mbox{min}\left\lbrace c^Tx + h^Ty \mid  (x,y) \in S \right\rbrace $$
Where $S=\left\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^n_+ \times \mathbb{R}^p_+ \mid Ax+Gy =b\right\rbrace $.
Assume that MILP admits a finite optimum.
Then if
$$\mbox{LP}_0:\hspace{0,2cm}\mbox{min}\left\lbrace c^Tx + h^Ty \mid  (x,y) \in P_0 \right\rbrace $$ where $P_0=\left\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ \times \mathbb{R}^p_+ \mid Ax+Gy =b\right\rbrace$, there is an optimal solution for $LP_0$.

The intuition say me that it must be truth because if you don't have an optimal solution in $LP_0$ is becuase you are not in a bounded region so you get contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider minimizing $x_1$ subject to $x_1=\sqrt{2}x_2$, with $n=2$ and $p=0$. The only integer feasible solution is $(0,0)$, but the LP relaxation is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I don't understand the example. The optimal solution in this case also $(0,0)$  since $x_1\geq 0$.

Comment: OK, I missed the lower bound.  So change the objective to minimize $-x_1$ instead (equivalently, maximize $x_1$).

Comment: Yes that's totally true. Sorry, actually I've thought it but in that moment I don't now why i have not seen it. Sorry again. I just realise, that the existence is true if the coeficcient instead of $\mathbb{R}$ are rational (for $A$,$G$,$h$,$b$,$c$) or if there is not degenerancy at the basic feasible solution of the $LP$ relaxation. Should be truth then right? I'm not really sure about the no degenerancy.